# Android. How to disable on click tab in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Android. How to disable on click tab in Viewpager?

Below there is my tabs:[image]

Comment: `@android:clickable="false"`

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

in onCreate() add buttons give them ids and variables, then attach disabled when you want.

```
Button button1, button2;
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     // do onCreate(); stuff
     button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_problem_type);
     button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_picture_type);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
     super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState );
     button1.setEnabled(false);
     button2.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: has this answer helped @tomaszcatarski ?